# getting the values of specific string values in registry keys with powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, key

Using the following powershell script:

```
Get-ChildItem hkcu:\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

I am able to get the following output:

```
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices\Entry1
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices
PSChildName  : Entry1
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
Device       : 2882881001
Recordable   : Yes
Active       : Yes

PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices\Entry2
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices
PSChildName  : Entry2
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
Device       : 2882881002

PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices\Entry3
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices
PSChildName  : Entry3
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
Device       : 2882881003
```

Which is great, it's showing me the infomation I want, but all I really need is the values of the string entry called 'Device' so all I actually want is the output of the script to look like this:

```
Device       : 2882881001
Device       : 2882881002
Device       : 2882881003
```

or ideally, this:

```
2882881001
2882881002
2882881003
```

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem hkcu:\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | where-object {$_.Device} | Foreach-Object {$_.Device}
```

will give you the requested output.

(In your example the Where-Object is not really required)

Answer (score 5):

This should work as well:

```
$path = 'hkcu:\Test\Universe\Datawink\Switch1\Devices'
Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Device
```